# Why doesn't my scalene triangle test work correctly?

Tags: python

Checking Scalene Triangle ( I am learning from http://www.pyschools.com)

I do not know what I am wrong ,Because I could not pass this test.

Write a function `isScalene(x, y, z)` that accepts the `3 sides` of a triangle as inputs. The function should return True if it is a scalene triangle. A scalene triangle has no equal sides.

Examples

```
>>> isScalene(2, 4, 3)
True
>>> isScalene(3, 3, 3)
False
>>> isScalene(0, 2, 3)
False
>>> isScalene(2, 2, 3)
False
```

My function define like this :

```
def isScalene(x, y, z): 
    if(x > 0 and y >0 and z> 0):
        if(x!=y!=z):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Could anyone give me a tip?

Comment: [OT] It's been ages since I last heard *scalene*... It's one of those terms that seem big in school but are *never* used in higher mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try being more expressive, I suspect your x!=y!=z is the problem.

```
if ( ( x != y ) and ( x != z ) and ( y !=z ) )
```

Comment: Or, more succinctly, `x!=y!=z!=x`. [Python comparator chaining](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comparison)

Answer (score 4):

What if the inputs are 2, 3, 5? (Hint: not a triangle at all!)

Answer (score 0):

```
def isScalene(x, y, z): 
    if x <= 0 or y <= 0 or z <= 0:
            return False
    if x + y > z and x - y < z:
       if x !=y != z:
          return True
    return False
```

you should check the scalene triangle must be a triangle first!